# Advanced placement CS A Exam

Tags: reference-request, education

What would be the standard topics covered in an 'Advanced Placement Computer Science A' test? Is there any good study reference someone can share?

**Edit: Answer**

An adjustment for my search term returned a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Placement_Computer_Science) just for this type of exam and the AB version.

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: I have been told this is bad practice.  I have left no answer in order to hopefully get a better refference also as I am probly not the best to leave an answer.

Comment: It is okay to answer your own questions on StackExchange sites.

Comment: @BrandonClark: I don't know who told you this, but it is in fact [officially encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) and we don't have a diverging policy. The idea is that you can leave your own answer and the community tells you by voting whether a better answer exists (in the ideal case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following book as a resource material and it was pretty good:

> [Barron's AP Computer Science A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764143735)

You can see the book preview there along with the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The [Litvin book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982477503) is also pretty good, as is the [Princeton Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764143735). I have had APCS students use all 3 and wind up nickeling the test.

Comment: What does nickeling mean? I sure it is not one of [these](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nickeling)

Comment: @GuyCoder It means scoring a 5 (maximum score) on APs.